# Can't link my library Angular in another library Angular

Tags: angular, npm

## Context

I created several independent angular libraries in different folders:

- /home/user/lib1
- /home/user/lib2
- /home/user/lib3

The lib2 and lib3 libraries have a dependency on the lib1 library.

```
// Example of the lib3.module.ts 
import {Lib1Module} from '@libs/lib1';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Lib3Component],
  imports: [
    Lib1Module
  ],
  exports: [Lib3Component]
})
export class Lib3Module { }
```

However, when I create a symlink of lib1 and import it into lib2 and lib3 with the command "npm link lib1", I get a build issue (bellow, you can see the error message).

```
ERROR: : Unexpected value 'Lib1Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib1/dist/libs/lib1/libs-lib1.d.ts' imported by the module 'Lib2Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib2/projects/libs/lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

The most amazing thing in all this, is, if I deploy my component on the official repository of npm, it will work. It's the same structure and files! So there is a problem with the symlink.

## What I tried

I tried to follow the solutions proposed here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10665

## How to reproduce my problem

I've reproduced an example here: https://github.com/fjoalland/multiple-angular-lib/tree/master

Just follow the steps and you should have the same error as me.

## Error message

Bellow, the full error I got when I try to build the lib2 with a symlink of the lib1

```
[root@user lib2]# ng build
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@libs/lib2'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: : Unexpected value 'Lib1Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib1/dist/libs/lib1/libs-lib1.d.ts' imported by the module 'Lib2Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib2/projects/libs/lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

An unhandled exception occurred: : Unexpected value 'Lib1Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib1/dist/libs/lib1/libs-lib1.d.ts' imported by the module 'Lib2Module in /home/user/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib2/projects/libs/lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

See "/tmp/ng-V1D4qF/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The contents of the angular-error.log file:

```
[error] Error: : Unexpected value 'Lib1Module in D:/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib1/dist/libs/lib1/libs-lib1.d.ts' imported by the module 'Lib2Module in D:/Documents/multiple-angular-lib/lib2/projects/libs/lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documents\multiple-angular-lib\lib2\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:73:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Documents\multiple-angular-lib\lib2\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:4:58)
```

Comment: Please post the error log it generates

Comment: There are a log here -> See "/tmp/ng-V1D4qF/angular-errors.log

Comment: @Robertgarcia thank you for your help! I edited my post and you can see the content of the angular-error.log at the end. Did you try the github I put in my post? Do you have the same error? Thanks again

Comment: Nobody has an answer to resolve that? I don't understand why it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to resolve your problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31989#issuecomment-523396480

There is a problem with the compilation of angular and how it manages the symlink from NPM. So you need to use **yarn** instead of **npm**, just to write your symlink (yarn link).